# A Problem I faced using Bitwise Operators in C (HackerRank)

Tags: c, algorithm, xor, bitwise-and

[HackerRank *Bitwise Operators*](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bitwise-operators-in-c/problem)

> In this challenge, you will use logical bitwise operators. All data is stored in its binary representation. The logical operators, and C language, use 1 to represent true and 0 to represent false. The logical operators compare bits in two numbers and return true or false, 0 or 1, for each bit compared.
>
> - *Bitwise AND operator &*  The output of bitwise AND is 1 if the corresponding bits of two operands is 1. If either bit of an operand is 0, the result of corresponding bit is evaluated to 0. It is denoted by &.
> - *Bitwise OR operator |*  The output of bitwise OR is 1 if at least one corresponding bit of two operands is 1. It is denoted by |.
> - *Bitwise XOR (exclusive OR) operator ^*  The result of bitwise XOR operator is 1 if the corresponding bits of two operands are opposite. It is denoted by ^.
>
> *For example, for integers 3 and 5,*
>
> ```
> 3 = 00000011 (In Binary)
> 5 = 00000101 (In Binary)
>
> AND operation        OR operation        XOR operation
>   00000011             00000011            00000011
> & 00000101           | 00000101          ^ 00000101
>   ________             ________            ________
>   00000001  = 1        00000111  = 7       00000110  = 6
> ```
>
> You will be given an integer ***n***, and a threshold, ***k***. For each number *i* from 1 through *n*, find the maximum value of the *logical and*, *or* and *xor* when compared against all integers through *n* that are greater than *i*. Consider a value only if the comparison returns a result less than *k* [else **0**].
> Print the results of the *and*, *or* and *exclusive or* comparisons on separate lines, in that order.
>
> **Example**
> *n* = 3
> *k* = 3
>
> The results of the comparisons are below:
>
> ```
> a b   and or xor
> 1 2   0   3  3
> 1 3   1   3  2
> 2 3   2   3  1
> ```
>
> For the *and* comparison, the maximum is **2**. For the *or* comparison, none of the values is less than ***k***, so the maximum is **0**. For the *xor* comparison, the maximum value less than ***k*** is **2**. The function should print:
>
> ```
> 2
> 0
> 2
> ```
>
> **Function Description**
>
> Complete the calculate_the_maximum function in the editor below.
>
> calculate_the_maximum has the following parameters:
>
> - int n: the highest number to consider
> - int k: the result of a comparison must be lower than this number to be considered
>
> **Prints**
>
> Print the maximum values for the *and*, *or* and *xor* comparisons, each on a separate line.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The only line contains **2** space-separated integers, ***n*** and ***k***.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> - 2 <= *n* <= 10<sup>3</sup>
> - 2 <= *k* <= *n*
>
> **Sample Input 0**
>
> ```
> 5 4
> ```
>
> **Sample Output 0**
>
> ```
> 2
> 3
> 3
> ```

**So This is My Answer**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void calculate_the_maximum(int n, int k) {
  int m1=0,m2=0,m3=0;
  for (int x=1; x<n; x++){
      for (int y=2; y<=n; y++){
          //and
          int a=x&y;
          if((a>m1) && (a<k)){
            m1=a;
          };
          //or
          int b=x|y;
          if((b>m2) && (b<k)){
            m2=b;
          };
          //xor
          int c=x^y;
          if((c>m3) && (c<k)){
            m3=c;
          };
      }
  }
  
  printf("%d \n",m1);
  printf("%d \n",m2);
  printf("%d \n",m3);
}

int main() {
    int n, k;
  
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
    calculate_the_maximum(n, k);
 
    return 0;
}
```

**And My Output is**

```
3 
3 
3
```

**Expected Output**

```
2
3
3
```

What is the mistake of my code?

Comment: `int m1,m2,m3=0;` That only inits the last variable. You need `int m1=0, m2=0, m3=0;` You should be able to pick such errors up by debugging your code. For example, run in a debugger, step thru the code and examine the flow and variable values as it runs.

Comment: its worked, but now it gives output as 3,3,3

Comment: Still the same advice - do debugging.

Comment: oh thanx, I'll run a debugger and try

Comment: Turn on your compiler's warnings! It would have told you about the first problem. With gcc, I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`

Comment: It seems like you're required to find the maximums given that x != y.

Comment: x = 3, y = 3 will produce the result m1 = 3. I think may be it ignore the case x = y

Comment: This is O(n^2). I think you can be a lot faster. Because you have all numbers from 1 to n and not just an array of size n it shouldn't be that difficult. Probably O(logn) is possible.

Comment: `My Output is` for *what input*?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



void calculate_the_maximum(int n, int k) {
  int m1=0,m2=0,m3=0;
  for (int x=1; x<n; x++){
      for (int y=x+1; y<=n; y++){
          //and
          int a= x & y;
          if((a>m1) && (a<k)){
            m1=a;
          };
          //or
          int b=x|y;
          if((b>m2) && (b<k)){
            m2=b;
          };
          //xor
          int c=x^y;
          if((c>m3) && (c<k)){
            m3=c;
          };
      }
  }
  
  printf("%d \n",m1);
  printf("%d \n",m2);
  printf("%d \n",m3);
}

int main() {
    int n, k;
  
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
    calculate_the_maximum(n, k);
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't initialize "y" at 2. In your case, i and y can be the same values.
when i = 2, y can be equal to 2. But you cannot do this for the question. Start y from i+1.

```
    void calculate_the_maximum(int n, int k)
    {
      int max_or = 0;
      int max_and = 0;
      int max_xor = 0;

      int temp_xor = 0;
      int temp_and = 0;
      int temp_or = 0;
      //or = xor + and;
     for(int i = 1 ; i < n ; i++ )
     {
         for(int j = i+1 ; j <=n ; j++)
         {
              temp_xor = i ^ j;
              temp_and = i & j;
              temp_or = temp_xor + temp_and;

              if (temp_xor > max_xor && temp_xor < k) max_xor = temp_xor;
              if (temp_and > max_and && temp_and < k) max_and = temp_and;
              if (temp_or > max_or && temp_or < k) max_or = temp_or;
         }

    }

    //print
    cout << max_and << endl << max_or << endl << max_xor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do just 1 change that is, in the inner loop, start y from x+1,

`for (int y=x+1; y<=n; y++)`

and all set

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This was my answer
I first converted to binary then converted it back

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    //Complete the following function.


    void calculate_the_maximum(int n, int k)
    {
        int i,j,a,b;
        int max_and = 0;
        int max_or = 0;
        int max_xor = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < n+1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j < n+1; j++)
            {
                if (j>i)
                {
                    a = i;
                    b = j;
                    int count_1 = 0;
                    int sum_1 = 0;
                    int count_2 = 0;
                    int sum_2 = 0;

                    while (!(a==0))
                    {
                        sum_1 += (a%2)*(pow(10,count_1));
                        a = a/2;
                        count_1++;

                    }
                    while (!(b==0))
                    {
                        sum_2 += (b%2)*(pow(10,count_2));
                        b = b/2;
                        count_2++;
                    }
                    int sum_3 = 0;
                    int sum_4 = 0;
                    int sum_5 = 0;
                    int num_1 = 0;
                    int num_2 = 0;
                    int num_3 =0;
                    int count_3 = 0;
                    while (!((sum_1 == 0)&&(sum_2 == 0)))
                    {
                        if ((sum_1%10 == 1)&&(sum_2%10 == 1))
                        {
                            sum_3 += pow(10,count_3);

                        }
                        if ((sum_1%10 == 1)||(sum_2%10 == 1))
                        {
                            sum_4 += pow(10,count_3);
                        }
                        if (((sum_1%10 == 1)&&(sum_2%10 == 0))||((sum_1%10 == 0)&&(sum_2%10 == 1)))
                        {
                            sum_5 += pow(10,count_3);
                        }
                        sum_1 = sum_1/10;
                        sum_2 = sum_2/10;
                        count_3++;
                    }
                    int count_4 = 0;
                    while (!(sum_3 == 0))
                    {
                        num_1 += (sum_3%10)*(pow(2,count_4));
                        sum_3 = sum_3/10;
                        count_4++;
                    }
                    int count_5 = 0;
                    while (!(sum_4 == 0))
                    {
                        num_2 += (sum_4%10)*(pow(2,count_5));
                        sum_4 = sum_4/10;
                        count_5++;
                    }
                    int count_6 = 0;
                    while (!(sum_5 == 0))
                    {
                        num_3 += (sum_5%10)*(pow(2,count_6));
                        sum_5 = sum_5/10;
                        count_6++;
                    }

                    if ((max_and < num_1)&&(num_1<k))
                    {
                        max_and = num_1;


                    }
                    if ((max_or < num_2)&&(num_2<k))
                    {
                        max_or = num_2;

                    }
                    if ((max_xor < num_3)&&(num_3<k))
                    {
                        max_xor = num_3;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n%d\n%d",max_and,max_or,max_xor);
    }

    int main() {
        int n, k;

        scanf("%d %d", &n, &k);
        if (!((n < 2)||(n > 1000)||(k < 2)||(k >n)))
        {
            calculate_the_maximum(n, k);
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error!\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
```